# Android: Create different APKs of the same App with different Icons

Tags: android, icons, apk

The companys that use my app want their own icon as the app icon. Since it isn't possible to change the app icon programmatically (or is it?), I need to create multiple apks with different icons.
 How could this be done easily (20 different apks) in as few clicks as possible? Is there a tool or something that could do this? or do I need to write my own plugin and if yes, do you have any links on how to do that in eclipse (I've never created a plugin for eclipse before...)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since it isn't possible to change the app icon programmatically (or is it?)

Not really.

> How could this be done easily (20 different apks) in as few clicks as possible?

Move your production builds to use [Gradle for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and set up a product flavor for each customer. You will be able to have different versions of the icon, and other stuff if needed (e.g., custom string resources with the customer's name), and Gradle can build custom APKs for each product flavor.